# excel overwrite dialog close

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

how to supress overright diaglog box when i use below code in asp.net, c#, sqlserver 2005

```
                Worksheet sheet1 = (Worksheet)wb1.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
                Worksheet sheet2 = (Worksheet)wb2.Worksheets["temp"];

                sheet1.Copy(sheet2, missing);
                wb1.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                wb2.SaveAs(dst, XlFileFormat.xlExcel3, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                wb2.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like

`Application.DisplayAlerts = false` ?